# Create Individual as Site/Community GUEST user

Tags: guest-user, individual

I want a Community public page to create a Lead, and I want to capture a consent checkbox, which should live on the Individual object. The guest profile does not include the Individual object, and I can't think of a way to create that Individual record automatically AND to populate it with a field that I can expose on a public Community/Site page.

I have tried making a Visualforce page and setting the controller to "without sharing," but I'm guessing it will fail when I try to click Save.

I have tried making a visual Flow, but that fails every time the public user tries to insert the Individual record.

I started to create a trigger to create the Individual automatically, but I realized that I could not automatically populate the Individual checkbox, so that would work for certain profiles, but not for the guest profile.

Has anyone had experience creating an Individual from a public page? And populating an "I accept the terms of service" checkbox on the Individual record?

Comment: Custom Apex controller runs in system mode, it will be able to create your Individual object.

Comment: That's great news. Who would be the owner of the Individual record, then? Is it possible for a user who doesn't have permission to create a record to own it?

Comment: Your code will set the owner by looking up Account/Contact/Lead/whatever  and sticking the Id of one of those records in `OwnerId` field on Individual.